# JavaScript to toggle relay through website

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, raspberry-pi

I apologize I am new to javascript. I am trying to toggle a relay from a website using setInterval. The relay is a Sainsmart with 16 channels and it is connected to an arduino controlled by a raspberry pi. The goal is to eventually have three independent relays toggling at particular intervals. However, every attempt to get the first one working fails. In addition, every time I add a setInterval within a function or global, freezes the live streaming video from my ip camera. I am using a sandbox key through ably.

The html code and script work to toggle the relay on, and then a second button will toggle it off, but I need a single button to accomplish it.

The button initiates the sequence with a counter dictating whether the relay toggles on or off. It is set up to toggle on with an even number and off with an odd number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the updated code I am trying to work with.

```
<div class="grid-item"><button id="37" onclick="startOnOff()">Start</button> 
</div>

<script src="http://cdn.ably.io/lib/ably.min-1.js"></script>
<script>

var count = 0;
function startOnOff() {
  var on = "37" + "on";
  var off = "37" + "off";
  if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    toggleRelay(on);
    count += 1;
  } else if (count % 2 == 1) {
    toggleRelay(off);
  }
  setInterval(startOnOff, 2000);
}
```

Comment: What does `var counter = 0;` doing inside `cyclePiston` function..?

Comment: Count the number of opening curly braces, and the number of closing braces. See what's wrong with that.

Comment: I didn't see that. I have been trying so many different combinations and things I've seen other people suggest I screwed those up. I fixed the braces and now the camera is streaming again, but I still can't get the setInterval to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have `count` in a few places and `counter` in one place where it should be `count`.

Assuming `toggleRelay()` is defined somewhere else in your code, try this:

```
var count = 0;
var on = "37" + "on";
var off = "37" + "off";

function startOnOff() {

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        toggleRelay(on);
    } else {
        toggleRelay(off);
    }

    count += 1;
    setTimeout(startOnOff, 2000);

}
```

- `count += 1;` should be outside of the `if` conditional statement,
- and use `setTimeout()` when calling `startOnOff()` recursively.